# wp_list_page insert an element after each link page

Tags: wordpress

make a horizontal menu (not nav)  in the header for pages

piece of code

```
<ul> 
             
             <li> 
                 <a href="#"> English </ a> 
             </li> 
             <li> <div class="separate"> </ div> </ li> 
             <li> ......more .....
</ul>
```

after

```
<ul> 

             <? php wp_list_pages ('title_li = '); ?> 
             <li> <div class="separate"> </ div> </ li> 
</ul>
```

separate - css

```
div.separate {  
    border-right: 1px dashed #000;
}
```

how to make a vertical line in this case was after each link?

sorry , first contacted wordpress

Comment: Something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/3K8tN/ - if I understand you correctly?

Comment: @stealthyninja yep, u absolutely right

Comment: Great. I'll post that as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li:after {
    content: " | ";
}
ul li:last-child:after {
    content: "";
}
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/3K8tN/

Comment: thought that we should do something like a cycle ... and then the whole thing in css , thx very much